# Warping Image in android

Tags: android

I need to warp image as like in application **Photo Warp** in google Play. I do with warp as in 
[BitMapmesh.java](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapMesh.java.shtml) But, i need other type that is in **Photo Warp**

[Warp http://evergreenhits.com/ad/PhotoShare.png](http://evergreenhits.com/ad/PhotoShare.png)

Kindly give me any suggestions.

Comment: I am also in need of the same one.Do anyone having any idea. Any reference to do this?

Comment: @Dray you got a solution for this please paste your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779669/how-to-morphing-on-image-in-android

Comment: have you any idea or code at this time? same que. +1